# Adm zip write zip buffer to ExpressJS response

Tags: node.js, express, buffer, response

Hi I'm trying to send a zip buffer made by Adm Zip npm module to my response for client download.
I manage to download the zip file but unable to expand it. OSX says "error 2 No such file or directory"...

The downlaoded zip file has got the right size I believe and is sent over this way:

```
var zip = new AdmZip();
// added files with zip.addFile(...)
var zipFile = zip.toBuffer();
res.contentType('zip');
res.write(zipFile);
res.end();
```

Any idea what could be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it comes from the Adm-zip code base and hasn't been merged yet:
https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/compare/master...mygoare:unzipErr